# THREE.js not loading materials onto object

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Taking mtl+obj files that were previously used in an ios app to load a 3d pcb chip into a scene.

When loading it using [three.js (r80)](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/), the object loads and the geometry looks correct, but none of the textures, colors or images load onto the object. Am i doing something wrong?

[MTL file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiliconLabs/thunderboard-ios/master/ThunderBoard/Thunderboard_React_031716_obj.mtl)

[OBJ File](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiliconLabs/thunderboard-ios/master/ThunderBoard/Thunderboard_React_031716_obj.obj)

All the images referenced in the mtl file are sitting in the same directory as the mtl+obj files, and I see that that are requested and served to the browser properly.

In XCode the object looks correct:
[image: thunderboard in ios]

Loaded in Blender, it has correct colors, but not of the images get projected onto the object:
[image: thunderboard in blender]

Loaded via three.js its just a black object:
[image: thunderboard in three.js]

JS code I'm using:

```js
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    init();

    function init() {
        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.load( "Thunderboard.mtl", function( materials ) {
            materials.preload();
            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
            objLoader.load("Thunderboard.obj", function ( object ) {
                scene.add(object);
            });
        });

        camera.position.z = 3;
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding some lights to the scene?

Comment: let there be light!

Comment: the colors are all correct, but the images are still not projecting onto the sides of the chip. any thoughts there?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the images weren't still loaded before you call renderer.render. Just an idea. 
Try another renderer.render (or calling it) just after scene.add(object); since the loader works in asynchronous way.

Comment: That does not seem to be the issue. :(

Comment: I've tested your code locally with  no luck. I can now only suppose that there's maybe a lack of normals and/or UVs in your obj file. I'm just guessing.

Comment: Found it! in the material properties, the color has been set to 0, 0, 0. I've done the following after materials.preload(); :
for(key in materials.materials){

              if(materials.materials[key].map != null){

               materials.materials[key].color.r = 0.5;
               materials.materials[key].color.g = 1;
               
              }

            }
Just adjust the values to whatever works for you (as i mentioned in the previous comment, maybe there's something missing in the obj file.